# Iterating through javascript objects

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to loop over a list objects, but when the limit of products changes more than 1 item it gives me a error:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"

Code:

```
var itemsList = function (limit) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'http://domain.com/api/items?limit=' + limit + '');
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if ((request.readyState === 4) && (request.status === 200)) {
            var item = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

            for (var prop in item) {
                console.log("o." + prop + " = " + item[prop]);
            }
        }
    };
    request.send();
};

itemsList(2);
```

Comment: You are probably not generating valid JSON. If you have a list of items you have to create an array, e.g. `[{"foo": 42}, {"bar": 21}]`, not e.g. `{"foo": 42} {"bar": 21}`. Don't create JSON manually.

Comment: Show us your JSON array.

Comment: Can you post your JSON code as well?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki here it is Object {id: "123", age: 20, price: 66, img: "jo.jpg", date: "31/12/1984"}

Comment: without being parsed is : {"id":"123","age":20,"price":66,"img":"jo.jpg","date":"31/12/1984"}

Comment: it's work @MônicaR. if i do `var item = {id: "123", age: 20, price: 66, img: "( .-. )", date: "31/12/1984"};` , the for loop work  just fine.

Comment: Monica, we want to see the JSON when there is more than one item in it because that's where you describe the problem occurs.  Just do a `console.log(request.responseText)` before you call `JSON.parse()` and post what that shows.

Comment: @jfriend00 it gives me {"id":"123","age":20,"price":66,"img":"jo.jpg","date":"31/12/1984"} , i notice the problem give me only when i change the limit from 1 to more items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text you are sending in "request.responseText" to JSON.parse(request.responseText) must not be well formatted. Examine your text beofre JSON.parse(), perhaps with alert(request.responseText), and consider http://json.org.

Comment: You should be able to confirm or deny that the error is from the line "JSON.parse()" by placing an alert before and after, if a debugger does not make that clear. Since all so far commenting suspect that's it, and since "JSON.parse" takes a string, you should be able to reduce the example to just one line "JSON.parse('your text')", where you pass your JSON as a text string. If that works, there may be special character(s) in your response visible using "escape()" with alert (or document.write  and "view source"). If it fails, you can simplify the text by hand and return here if not obvious.